# Socket only accepts one Connection

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming, tuples

My Python socket chat with multithreading only accepts one connection. If I try to connect a second client it doesn't work. On the client side it seems like everything is okay but if i try to send a second message from client 2 the message doesn't arrive.

```
import socket
import threading

class TxtSocket:
    
    def __init__(self, host="127.0.0.1" , port=5555):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
        print("Socket was created")
        

    def server(self):
        self.s.listen()
        print("Server is listening")
        conn, addr = self.s.accept()
        print(f"{addr} is now connected.")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf8")
            print(data)
            if not data:
                break
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    txtsocket = TxtSocket()
    for i in range(0, 26):
        t = threading.Thread(target=txtsocket.server())
        t.start()

# Client
import socket

def Text():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5555))
    print("Connected")
    while True:
        message = input("Deine Nachricht: ")
        message = message.encode("utf8")
        s.send(message)
Text()
```

Comment: Create a new thread to handle client connection when socket gets a new connection to support multiple clients - posted server code works with multiple simultaneous clients connected to the server.

Comment: If the answer is helpful feel free to up-vote it so others know it's useful. Also note that Python has a SocketServer module that can make the server code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Need couple mods to the server to handle multiple clients.

- Need main loop to keep accepting new connections and forking off the processing to a thread
- Create a new thread to handle client connection when socket gets a new connection.

The following server code works with multiple running clients as specified above.

```python
# server
import socket
import threading

class TxtSocket:
    
    def __init__(self, host="127.0.0.1", port=5555):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.thread = 0
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
        print("Socket was created")
        
    def handle(self, conn, addr):
        self.thread += 1
        print(f"Thread-{self.thread} {addr} is now connected")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print(data.decode("utf8"))
        conn.close()

    def server(self):
        # specify the number of unaccepted connections that the server
        # will allow before refusing new connections.
        self.s.listen(5)
        print(f'Server listening on tcp:{self.host}:{self.port}')
        while True:
            conn, addr = self.s.accept()
            # create new thread to handle the client connection
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.handle, args=(conn, addr))
            t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    txtsocket = TxtSocket()
    txtsocket.server()
```

Note that Python has a [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) module that can make some of this easier with a TCPServer that does much of the work. See server [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example).

Answer (score 0):

you can use thread for close other connections

```
import socket
from _thread import start_new_thread

server = socket...
first_connection = None

def check_con_isalive():
    try:
        while True:
            first_connection.send(b"\0")
    except Exception:
        print("connnection was closed")
        first_connection.close()
        


def thread_con(con):
    global first_connection
    if not first_connection:
        first_connection = con
        start_new_thread(check_con_isalive, ())
        ...
    else:
        print("blocking new connections")
        con.close()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        con, adr = server.accept()
        start_new_thread(thread_con, (con, ))
```